# Mysterious JavaFx fillPolygon rendering bug

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, rendering, polygon

Today I faced a problem in the following situation: I have a lot of polygons that I want to draw to a JavaFX Canvas using fillPolygon(...), but for no clear reason some of the fillings are sometimes distorted (within the bounding box of the polygons). The strange about it: it seems to occur only under the following circumstances (as shown in the example below):

- a LineChart (or any other chart) is in the scene graph
- the canvas must have a certain minimum width
- a certain amount of polygons are drawn
- the polygons have special coordinates

The problem occurs on my Windows7 machine (64bit) with Java JDK 1.8.0_73

I tracked the problem down to the self-containing example below. When you start, paint() is called and all polygons are drawn just fine at the top of the window. When I press a key, paint() is called again but the polygons are distorted.

Any hints are appreciated. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PolygonBug
extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    throws Exception {

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1500, 50);
        LineChart<Number,Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        VBox box = new VBox(canvas, chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed((e) -> paint(canvas));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        paint(canvas);
    }

    private void paint(Canvas canvas) {

        // create coordinates
        List<double[][]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new double[][]{new double[]{100,  60,  60, 100}, new double[]{30, 10, 30, 30}});
        list.add(new double[][]{new double[]{110, 113, 116, 110}, new double[]{30, 10, 30, 30}});
        list.add(new double[][]{new double[]{130, 133, 136, 130}, new double[]{30, 10, 30, 30}});

        // clear canvas and draw polygons
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

        for (int i=0; i<5000; i++) {
            for (double[][] coords : list) {
                gc.fillPolygon(coords[0], coords[1], coords[0].length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Distorted drawing]

Comment: What is the point of `for (int i=0; i<5000; i++)`?  Is your actual code drawing more than just those three polygons?

Comment: Yes, my actual code draws about 8000 polygons. As said, we need a lot of `fillPolygon()` calls to draw to get the described effect of distortion, so I added the loop above to get the same effect using my three test polygons. Meanwhile, I use a Swing `BufferedImage` as workaround, call `bufferedImage.fillPolygon()` multiple times and draw that `bufferedImage` to the FX Canvas using `gc.drawImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, new WritableImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight()))`. This works fine but I'm sure that this isn't the most performant solution.

Comment: I checked this on a Mac with JDK 8u122 and I did not see any difference between the first any any other call to the paint method.

Comment: Ok, I installed JDK 1.8.0_102 (32 bit), everything works fine. Switching back to 1.8.0_73 (32 bit), the error is reproducible again. So, for me it seems that it was a bug in older JRE/JDK versions being solved in the newest version, even if I didn't find a corresponding release note entry.